# Bootstrap: Collapse other sections when one is expanded

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am making a Rails app, and am trying to achieve a particular functionality relating to Twitter's Bootstrap [collapse](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse). Bear with me as I explain it.

I currently have the following view:

[image]

When each of these buttons is clicked, their data-toggle div is expanded. The view is set-up as follows:

```
    <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#keys"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Keys <span class="badge badge-info pull-right"><%= @app.keys.count %></span></button>
    <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#attrs"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Attributes</button>
    <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#edit"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Edit Details</button>

    <div class="collapse indent" id="keys">
        <!--content-->
    </div>

    <div class="collapse indent" id="attrs">
        <!--content-->
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="edit">
        <!--content-->
    </div>
```

I have them set-up like this, because I want the buttons side by side, in a row. If I move the buttons to be right above the view they expand/collapse, then the buttons stack on top of one another.

So, my end goal is to have the three buttons side-by-side and have them collapse and expand their respective sections. The current set-up works, however is a little awkward. For example, if someone expands the keys section and then expands the attributes section, they have to scroll below the keys section.

There are two possible solutions to this problem. One is that pressing one button causes the other 2 to collapse themselves. This would mean that at any given time, only one of these sections is expanded.

The better solution, I think would be to have it so that when keys is expanded, the buttons to the right move down to the bottom of the keys div, and when attributes is expanded, the edit details button moves to the bottom of that div. Is this possible? I have already tried to do it by letting the buttons stack on top of each other and changing their relative locations through css, but that didn't work because when one of the sections was expanded, the other buttons ended up in awkward spots in the middle of the expanded section.

Lastly, I would like to try to do this without the accordion style behavior as mentioned on twitter's bootstrap page, but if someone can convince me from a design standpoint that it is preferable, I would certainly reconsider.

Comment: Have you looked into the `data-parent` attribute ..?

Comment: No, but I will and I'll come back and let you know if that helped. Thanks!

Comment: That didn't work for me. I'm not sure, I may have done something wrong. Any help would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Using `data-parent`, first solution is to stick to the example selector architecture

```html
<div id="myGroup">
    <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#keys" data-parent="#myGroup"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Keys  <span class="badge badge-info pull-right">X</span></button>
    <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#attrs" data-parent="#myGroup"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Attributes</button>
    <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#edit" data-parent="#myGroup"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Edit Details</button>

    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="collapse indent" id="keys">
            keys
        </div>

        <div class="collapse indent" id="attrs">
            attrs
        </div>

        <div class="collapse" id="edit">
            edit
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/nuNsp/83/)

Second solution is to bind on the events and hide the other collapsible elements yourself.

```js
var $myGroup = $('#myGroup');
$myGroup.on('show.bs.collapse','.collapse', function() {
    $myGroup.find('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
});
```

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/ytstP/22/)

PS: the strange effect in the demos is caused by the `min-height` set for the example, just ignore that.

---

Edit: changed the JS event from `show` to `show.bs.collapse` as specified in [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events).

Comment: The `data-parent` info was invaluable in getting this to work. Thanks!

Comment: For me, that `<div class="accordion-group">...</div>` was the missing piece. Simply using `data-parent` didn't help. I didn't see the requirement of `accordion-group` class in bootstrap's documentation. Thanks!

Comment: @Srinidhi It's all about this selector : [`'> .accordion-group > .in'` (src on github)](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-collapse.js#L59)

Comment: Broken like in "this jsfiddle is broken".

Comment: @LéonPelletier CDN urls broke, I updated but you should also look into v3 as those examples are for v2

Comment: This doesnt work on Bootstrap 3. Issue opened: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10966

Comment: The first solution doesn't work for BS3 if your markup isn't conforming to a very strict hierarchy of elements. Solution 2 is therefore better.

Comment: you save my life. i just forgot to add id="accordion" in parent div

Comment: @Björn-Ali-Göransson: Second solution doesn't work with web-accessing Android devices ... 
issue seems to be that Android doesn't send Ajax requests because of the property "cache" which is set to true by default.
Therefore I recommend following the strict hierarchy of elements as bootstrap says: 
id="X"   >   class="panel"   >   data-parent="#X"

Comment: First solution works in Bootstrap 3.3.7... I just happened to have it implemented incorrectly, my mistake. I'm glad I found out through the above answer that I needed to make sure that the data-parent's info was matching the parent div (that contained ALL the buttons or whatever had to collapse)

Comment: Has anyone a javascript solution for bootstrap 5?

Answer (score 52):

If you don't want to change your markup, this function does the trick:

```
jQuery('button').click( function(e) {
    jQuery('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Whenever a BUTTON is clicked, all sections become collapsed. Then bootstrap opens the one you selected.

Comment: This generic solution worked very well for me. I did not want to use a typical accordion group and this was perfect. Thanks!

Comment: What is `(e)` here?

Comment: @Nofel e = eventObject  You can use it - for instance- to prevent the default click behavior this way: e.preventDefault();

Comment: Ah, my accordion are created on the fly when I click "Add" , how can I add to the code that the last generated one get to show instead of hide. I tried this but doesn't work ` $('button').click( function(e) {$('.collapse').collapse('hide'); $('.collapse').last().collapse('show');`
                      });

Comment: If you want to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955803/making-last-dynamic-added-accordion-open) question

Comment: @Nofel what about `$('.collapse:not(:last-child)').collapse('hide');`

Comment: Congratulations, it took hours and hours to solve this!

Answer (score 36):

> For **Bootstrap v5**

Add the `data-bs-parent` attribute to the `collapse` elements. Thanks to @Diana for the update.

> For **Bootstrap v4.1**

Add the `data-parent` attribute to the `collapse` elements instead on the `button`.

```html
<div id="myGroup">
    <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#keys"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Keys  <span class="badge badge-info pull-right">X</span></button>
    <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#attrs"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Attributes</button>
    <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#edit"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Edit Details</button>

    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="collapse indent" id="keys"  data-parent="#myGroup">
            keys
        </div>

        <div class="collapse indent" id="attrs"  data-parent="#myGroup">
            attrs
        </div>

        <div class="collapse" id="edit"  data-parent="#myGroup">
            edit
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me when the toggle stopped working when I upgraded from Bootstrap 3.3.6 to the latest v4

Comment: Worked excellent for me on Bootstrap 4.3.1. Thank you for providing this simple fix ! 

Comment: this is what i needed for BS 4.6.0, big thanks!

Comment: Works on BS5, just use data-bs-parent instead.

Comment: Does this only work if the group element is the direct parent of the buttons?

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Bootstrap 4, and you don't want to change your markup:

```
var $myGroup = $('#myGroup');
$myGroup.on('show.bs.collapse','.collapse', function() {
$myGroup.find('.collapse.show').collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: Doesn't help for nested lists FYI.

Answer (score 6):

**Bootstrap 3 example with side by side buttons below the content**

```css
.panel-heading {
  display: inline-block;
}

.panel-group .panel+.panel {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.panel {
  border: 0 !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collaple Group 3</a>
    </h4>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap 3 example with side by side buttons above the content**

```css
.panel-heading {
  display: inline-block;
}

.panel-group .panel+.panel {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.panel {
  border: 0 !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collaple Group 3</a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is important to note that Bootstrap 3 needs the class="panel" around the content blocks to work like an accordion.

Comment: @JonasEberle that was the key for me

Answer (score 3):

If you stick to HTML structure and proper selectors according to the Bootstrap convention, you should be alright.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp#accordion)

Comment: This information is correct but not an answer to his question because above solution sticks each section to be under its title while he needs to show all titles together then toggle between their content.

Answer (score 3):

In bootstrap 4 to close all collapseds works like this:

ACTION:

```
<button id="CloseAll" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse">Close All</button>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#CloseAll").on('click', function() {
        $(".collapse").removeClass("show");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$('.panel-defaul.ph').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).children('.panel-heading').addClass('panel-heading-collapsed');  
    $('.panel-defaul.ph').not(this).children('.panel-collapse').removeClass('in');
});
```

Comment: The `.not(this)` was the thing I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

working like a charm here for bootstrap 4>4.1.1

```
var myGroup = $('your-list');

myGroup.on('show.bs.collapse','.collapse', function() {
   myGroup.find('.collapse.show').collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: This looks identical to [Aberm's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46044615/719186)

Answer (score 1):

This was helpful for me:

```
    jQuery('button').click( function(e) {
    jQuery('.in').collapse('hide');
});
```

It's collapsed already open section.
Thnks to GrafiCode Studio

Answer (score 1):

On Bootstrap5

Like noticed in the docu you can use the "data-bs-parent=.." attribute

```
If parent is provided, then all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when this collapsible item is shown. (similar to traditional accordion behavior - this is dependent on the card class). The attribute has to be set on the target collapsible area.
```

[see more in bootstrap5 docu](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-bs-parent="#accordion"` on child elements and `id="accordion"` on parent element, using Bootstrap 5.

I needed similar functionality with cards, where clicking on one card button will expand current card and collapse other open/expanded card.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-evenly align-items-center m-3 flex-wrap" id="accordion">
    
    <div class="card col-md-3 m-2 p-2 text-center border border-dark-subtle rounded bg-primary-subtle" style="max-width:350px">
        <img class="card-img-top mx-auto my-2" src="#" style="max-width:300px">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#div1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="div1" >
                Colllapsable Div1          
            </button>
            <div class="collapse" id="div1" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
                <ul class="list-unstyled text-center">
                    <li>Item1</li>
                    <li>Item2</li>
                    <li>Item3</li>
                    <li>Item4</li>
                    <li>Item5</li>
                    <li>Item6</li>
                    <li>Item7</li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card col-md-3 m-2 p-2 text-center border border-dark-subtle rounded bg-primary-subtle" style="max-width:350px">
        <img class="card-img-top mx-auto my-2" src="#" style="max-width:300px">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#div2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="div2" >
                Colllapsable Div2         
            </button>
            <div class="collapse" id="div2" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
                <ul class="list-unstyled text-center">
                    <li>Item1</li>
                    <li>Item2</li>
                    <li>Item3</li>
                    <li>Item4</li>
                    <li>Item5</li>
                    <li>Item6</li>
                    <li>Item7</li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Method Works Properly For me:

```js
var lanopt = $(".language-option");

lanopt.on("show.bs.collapse",".collapse", function(){
   lanopt.find(".collapse.in").collapse("hide");
});
```