# Bootstrap Accordion button toggle "data-parent" not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create an accordion using Bootstrap 3 using the button collapsible with the data attribute, without the accordion markup. It just looks more cleaner to me.

However I cannot make the **data-parent** attribute to work. I want when opening a question, all others to close. I'm reading the docs ( http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage ) but still cannot get it to work.

I'm using the following code:

```
<div class="accordion" id="myAccordion">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-1" data-parent="#myAccordion">Question 1?</button>
    <div id="collapsible-1" class="collapse">
    <p>Etiam posuere quam ac quam. Maecenas aliquet accumsan leo. Nullam dapibus fermentum ipsum. Etiam quis quam. Integer lacinia. Nulla est.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-2" data-parent="#myAccordion">Question 2?</button>
    <div id="collapsible-2" class="collapse">
    <p>Etiam posuere quam ac quam. Maecenas aliquet accumsan leo. Nullam dapibus fermentum ipsum. Etiam quis quam. Integer lacinia. Nulla est.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-3" data-parent="#myAccordion">Question 3?</button>
    <div id="collapsible-3" class="collapse">
    <p>Etiam posuere quam ac quam. Maecenas aliquet accumsan leo. Nullam dapibus fermentum ipsum. Etiam quis quam. Integer lacinia. Nulla est.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/twinsen/AEew4/

I'll be very happy if someone points to me where I'm making a mistake :\

Answer (score 159, accepted):

**Bootstrap 4**

Use the `data-parent=""` attribute on the collapse element (instead of the trigger element)

```
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h5>
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible #1 trigger
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Collapsible #1 element
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ... (more cards/collapsibles inside #accordion parent)
</div>
```

---

**Bootstrap 3**

See this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10966

There is a "bug" that makes the accordion dependent on the `.panel` class when using the `data-parent` attribute. To workaround it, you can wrap each accordion group in a 'panel' div..

http://bootply.com/88288

```
<div class="accordion" id="myAccordion">
    <div class="panel">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-1" data-parent="#myAccordion">Question 1?</button>
        <div id="collapsible-1" class="collapse">
            ..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-2" data-parent="#myAccordion">Question 2?</button>
        <div id="collapsible-2" class="collapse">
            ..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-3" data-parent="#myAccordion">Question 3?</button>
        <div id="collapsible-3" class="collapse">
           ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comments, each section doesn't have to be a `.panel`. However...

- `.panel` must be a direct child of the element used as `data-parent=`
- each accordion section (`data-toggle=`) must be a direct child of the `.panel` (http://www.bootply.com/AbiRW7BdD6#)

Comment: In fact, you can wrap the entire group in a single `.panel` div. The important thing seems to be that the `.panel` is (1) a direct child of the `data-parent` and (2) the `.collapse` elements are direct children of a `.panel`.

Comment: ah, tx! 
> @fat: "this is the way it is because of nesting accordions"

Comment: `.panel` is only required if you want *accordion* behaviour, not just collapse: http://www.bootply.com/5XTEIviBwp

Comment: When i accessed your link, seems Server was down in bootply.com, We can make this work **using Jquery** , check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11479208/2218697) post.

Answer (score 17):

Note, not only there is dependency on .panel, it also has dependency on the DOM structure.

Make sure your elements are structured like this:

```
    <div id="parent-id">
        <div class="panel">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#opt1" data-parent="#parent-id">Control</a>
            <div id="opt1" class="collapse">
...
```

It's basically what @Blazemonger said, but I think the hierarchy of the target element matters too. I didn't finish trying every possibility out, but basically it should work if you follow this hierarchy.

FYI, I had more layers between the control div & content div and that didn't work.

Answer (score 15):

**Bootstrap 3**

Try this. Simple solution with no dependencies.

```js
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function() {
  $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide')
});
```

Answer (score 8):

As Blazemonger said, #parent, .panel, and .collapse have to be direct descendants. However, if you can't change your HTML, you can do a workaround using bootstrap events and methods with the following code:

```js
$('#your-parent .collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    var actives = $('#your-parent').find('.in, .collapsing');
    actives.each( function (index, element) {
        $(element).collapse('hide');
    })
})
```

Comment: This opens panel then immediately closes it

Comment: @kernowcode works fine for me, take a look http://jsfiddle.net/y9a3a3sp/

Answer (score 2):

I found this alteration to Krzysztof's answer helped my issue

```js
$('#' + parentId + ' .collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {            
    var all = $('#' + parentId).find('.collapse');
    var actives = $('#' + parentId).find('.in, .collapsing');
    all.each(function (index, element) {
      $(element).collapse('hide');
    })
    actives.each(function (index, element) {                
      $(element).collapse('show');                
    })
})
```

if you have nested panels then you may also need to specify which ones by adding another class name to distinguish between them and add this to the selector in the above JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (hopefully) universal patch I developed to fix this problem for BootStrap V3.  No special requirements other than plugging in the script.

```js
$(':not(.panel) > [data-toggle="collapse"][data-parent]').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).data('parent');
    var items = $('[data-toggle="collapse"][data-parent="' + parent + '"]').not(this);
    items.each(function() {
        var target = $(this).data('target') || '#' + $(this).prop('href').split('#')[1];
        $(target).filter('.in').collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** Below is a simplified answer which still meets my needs, and I'm now using a delegated click handler:

```
$(document.body).on('click', ':not(.panel) > [data-toggle="collapse"][data-parent]', function() {
    var parent = $(this).data('parent');
    var target = $(this).data('target') || $(this).prop('hash');
    $(parent).find('.collapse.in').not(target).collapse('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when toggling the accordion. But when I try to put the script block in   the header block, it works for my case!!

```
<head>   
...   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" />       
<script src="../assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>   
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.js" ></script> 
</head>
```