# Collapse with only one item opened not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to customize a collapse in my app. I've tried the accordion plugin that comes with the AngularJS UI Bootstrap, but it is rather complex, as what I need is only 2 links side by side and the collapsing elements opening in a row under, so I've decided to include the transition.js and collapse.js from Bootstrap.

So far my code looks like this:

```
<div class="logo" id="accordion">
      <a data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#login">
        Log In
      </a>

      <a data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#signup">
        Sign Up
      </a>

      <div id="signup" class="collapse">dfkñfkldsklñfdsñlkfd ñlkdflkfdñlfsdñl ksfdlkfdslñsfdñl kfdkfkldl fdksñlfdklfdñksfd

      <div id="login" class="collapse">blablabla</div>

</div>
```

The collapse effect works perfectly, but so far I haven't been able to accomplish the "only one item opened at a time" effect.

Might it be some kind of conflict with the AngularJS files?

Here's a [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YtpElwl92nFCRZUTnpqa?p=preview).

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19426220/1140134

Comment: @javaCity, this fixes the issue, but then it makes the targeted div appear under each link, and I can't place the links side by side like in the plunker. Any clue about how to fix this?

Comment: Fixed it! Just wrapped everything with a panel div, not each group.

Comment: Great! This was a weird bug..

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is you need to have two variables `loginCollapsed` and `signUpCollapsed` and manage the mutual exclusivity yourself in the controller. eg:

```
// untested
$scope.$watch('loginCollapsed', function(val){
  signUpCollapsed = !loginCollapsed;
})
```

The angular-ui guys set up some good practices and have an accordion that optionally opens one or many [bellows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion#Bellows):

Source of implementation:

```
if ( closeOthers ) {
  angular.forEach(this.groups, function (group) {
    if ( group !== openGroup ) {
      group.isOpen = false;
    }
  });
}
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js#L13

Comment: I'm not using AngularUI, I'm using plain Bootstrap. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Yup, and I'm showing you how to build a fish, not how to use one :)