# Responsive layout with collapsible components

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, foreach, responsive-design

I'm developing a website using laravel framework along with bootstrap and i need to do responsive layout with collapsible components! I need some help :)

### Large screen size:

Click on first picture:

[image] 
Click on second picture:

[image]

### Small screen size:

Click on first picture:

[image]

Click on second picture:

[image]

### At this moment i have this problem with large screen size:

[image]

### Code: [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/2oUwwpp0fb)

```
<section class="container full-width">
    <div class="row" id="accordion">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                  <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/fjmz0wv/axlmf39xl/tumblr_m6o0emjayw1ru64rao1_1280.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
            </a>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
                ...
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding cyan">
                ...
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
                ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                  <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/fjmz0wv/axlmf39xl/tumblr_m6o0emjayw1ru64rao1_1280.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
            </a>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
                ...
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding cyan">
                ...
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
                ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                  <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/fjmz0wv/axlmf39xl/tumblr_m6o0emjayw1ru64rao1_1280.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
            </a>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
                ...
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding cyan">
                ...
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
                ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Ok! How can I stretch the collapsible component? How works the bootstrap collapse for to close the others collapses when i click on other?

I hope I have been able to explain my problem :)

Thanks for your attention!

Edit:

[image]

## Solved:

### [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/IeQ7UlZC5T)

This layout on foreach (3 items per row)

```
<section class="container-fluid no-padding">
     <div class="row no-padding">
          <div id="accordion-lg">
               <div class="hidden-xs panel">
                    @foreach (array_chunk($collection, 3) as $row)
                         @foreach ($row as $item)
                         <a class="col-lg-4 no-padding" data-toggle="collapse" href="{{ '#collapse-lg'.$item->id }}" data-parent="#accordion-lg">
                              Collapse Toogle
                         </a>
                         @endforeach
                         @foreach ($row as $item)
                         <div id="{{ 'collapse-lg'.$item->id }}" class="collapse">
                              Collapse
                         </div>
                         @endforeach
                    @endforeach
               </div>
          </div>
          <div id="accordion-xs">
               <div class="hidden-lg panel">
               @foreach ($category->trips as $item)
                    <a class="col-xs-12 no-padding" data-toggle="collapse" href="{{ '#collapse-xs'.$item->id }}" data-parent="#accordion-xs">
                        Collapse Toogle
                    </a>
                    <div id="{{ 'collapse-xs'.$item->id }}" class="collapse">
                        Collapse
                    </div>
               @endforeach
               </div>
          </div>  
     </div>
</section>
```

Thaks for help to solve this problem!

Comment: What is the behavior you are wanting to achieve at each breakpoint when you click on each element? I have a semi-working bootply but I am not sure what it is you want each element to. Do you want each picture to only toggle the text below it or to also hide all other showing text?

Comment: I commented on your response leaving the layout that ready, only a problem arises in collapsible component that I have identified in comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, unfortunately, the behavior you want at these breakpoints is not possible without duplicating content. In essence, you will have two accordions, one which shows on lg and one for xs.

There are downsides to duplicating content (such as increased load times, higher maintenance, increased time to make changes, etc) but if you find them acceptable, I have the solution below.

I went ahead and refactored your code (while trying to maintain most of the things you were doing - such as no padding) and removed a lot of extra bootstrap classes which were not necessary. The two accordions are now completely split apart; the lg one comes first, then the xs one.

The code is available here: http://www.bootply.com/8sga1R1l0F

I also noticed another problem in the original code you supplied. When you would click on an element in the accordion, it would not hide any other element that was showing. This is due to the 'bug' discussed here: [Bootstrap 3 Accordion button toggle "data-parent" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425165/bootstrap-3-accordion-button-toggle-data-parent-not-working)

Let me know if  you have any questions.

For completeness, the full code is below:

HTML

```
<section class="container-fluid no-padding">
    <div class="row no-padding">
        <div class="hidden-xs">
            <a class="col-lg-4 no-padding" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseBottom">
                <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/fjmz0wv/axlmf39xl/tumblr_m6o0emjayw1ru64rao1_1280.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
            <a class="col-lg-4 no-padding" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseBottom">
                <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/fjmz0wv/axlmf39xl/tumblr_m6o0emjayw1ru64rao1_1280.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
            <a class="col-lg-4 no-padding" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseBottom">
                <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/fjmz0wv/axlmf39xl/tumblr_m6o0emjayw1ru64rao1_1280.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseBottom" class="hidden-xs collapse in">
                <div class="col-lg-4 no-padding">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 no-padding cyan">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 no-padding">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="xsAccordion">
            <div class="hidden-lg panel">
                <a class="col-xs-12 no-padding" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" data-parent="#xsAccordion">
                    <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/fjmz0wv/axlmf39xl/tumblr_m6o0emjayw1ru64rao1_1280.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse in">
                    <div>
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                    </div>
                    <div class="cyan">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-lg panel">
                <a class="col-xs-12 no-padding" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" data-parent="#xsAccordion">
                    <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/fjmz0wv/axlmf39xl/tumblr_m6o0emjayw1ru64rao1_1280.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse">
                    <div>
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                    </div>
                    <div class="cyan">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-lg panel">
                <a class="col-xs-12 no-padding" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" data-parent="#xsAccordion">
                    <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/fjmz0wv/axlmf39xl/tumblr_m6o0emjayw1ru64rao1_1280.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse">
                    <div>
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                    </div>
                    <div class="cyan">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.no-padding {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.cyan { 
    color: #00b1ba;
}
```

Comment: I see you have edited your question with more details, unfortunately, I do not think it is possible solve that issue without duplicating some content. If you don't mind doing that then I have a demo which should fit what you want. If this is what you are after, let me know and I will edit the original answer. http://www.bootply.com/VSYul2Pk30

Comment: Yes I edited! I noticed that was not very well explained :) However I just put two situations to use this layout :) I think that now is better! Ok! Starting from your demo, i made this layout but i have one more a problem that is: when I click on an image the other collapsible components should uncollapse :) Thanks for help! http://www.bootply.com/phc2wZ5mMh There is no problem to repeat the code?

Comment: However I've added something that was missing :) It Works! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

With bootstrap 4, you change the order of the elements using the order classes. First, arrange the elements in order that you want to display on mobile devices.

Then apply the `order-sm-*` classes to change the order on the devices which are larger than mobile devices.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
        <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
        <div>
            <div class="row d-flex flex-wrap">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info order-md-0 col col-md-4 col-sm-12" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
                <div id="demo" class="collapse order-md-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info order-md-1 col-md-4 col-sm-12" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#demo2">Simple collapsible</button>
                <div id="demo2" class="collapse order-md-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info order-md-2 col-md-4 col-sm-12" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#demo3">Simple collapsible</button>
                <div id="demo3" class="collapse order-md-5 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Screenshots

**Desktop**
[image]
**Mobile**
[image]

---

**Desktop Expanded**
[image]

**Mobile Expanded**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly following demo should work for you.. Check once.

http://www.bootply.com/cbtRf3xqaV

```
<section class="container full-width">
    <div class="row" id="accordion">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="left">
              <img src="test.jpg" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;">
            </a>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in left">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding clearfix">
                ...
                </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding cyan left">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
                </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
                ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
               <img src="test.jpg" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;">
            </a>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
                ...
                </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding cyan">
                ...
                </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
                ...
                </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" class="left">
                <img src="test.jpg" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;">
            </a>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse left">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding cyan">
                 the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
                when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
                </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

### Update:

Updated Demo: http://www.bootply.com/cbtRf3xqaV

Can you check once..

Comment: Hi irvgk! No, in the thirth image where I have the citations lorem ipsum wanted they are stretchy enough across the width of the screen as in the first image! Thanks for help!

Comment: thank you a lot for your help, but I think that you have not understood my problem, I edited the images of my topic to understand better, along with a demonstration of the code used. What is highlighted is what appears when I click on the first image! If you click on the second should also stretch on the width of the screen :)