# Bootstrap 3 Accordion stays open when collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating an accordion group using bootstrap 3, here is the code:

```
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
                <h3>Purchase No: 123 </h3>
                </a>
            </div>                
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         content here
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The code works fine when I open the accordion, but when I click it again (to close), it collapses, and open up again.

In short the accordion can't be closed once opened. I noticed the element changes at this particular div

```
 <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

In that state the the accordion is collapsed, and when I close it, the class changes to `collapsing` (showing the animation) then it is removed. But briefly after that, the class "collapsing" and "in" added again so in the browser when I try to close an accordion it will like somehow shows "bouncy" animation which make it never closed when I try to close it

Any suggestions?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19426220/3168859) might help you..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 Accordion button toggle "data-parent" not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425165/bootstrap-3-accordion-button-toggle-data-parent-not-working)

Comment: make sure you have added bootstrap js file and jquery as well in order first jquery js than bootstrap js because i just check on jsfiddle and your code is working fine with bootstrap and jquery added. http://jsfiddle.net/dajrct8v/

Comment: provide your live site's link, it'll help find any JavaScript conflicts. if any.

Comment: thanks all for the suggestions, but it is looks like i was using an older version of jquery which is not compatible with bootstrap 3, found this error on firefox's web inspector(idk but firebug does not point this error). I am now using jquery 2.x and the accordions works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks all for the suggestions, but it is looks like i was using an older version of jquery which is not compatible with bootstrap 3, found this error on firefox's web inspector(idk but firebug does not point this error). I am now using jquery 2.x and the accordions works perfectly