# Boostrap js collapse dont hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

everyone.
I' got problem with price list on my website.
Heres the url:

http://auto2000.waw.pl/cennik/

If you click "Przebieg" opens list of services and prices. When you click on it - hides .

However, if you click first "Przebieg" and then "Okres oksplatacji" (or another position), is to "Przebieg" does not hide .

Where could the problem lie ? I have no idea.

Heres the code from left column:

```
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <a class="btn btn-cennik" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#<?php the_sub_field('cennik_href'); ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                <?php the_sub_field('cennik_nazwa_sekcji'); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
```

Code js from boostrap.js was not processed in any way.
I use this js rule
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: Show us your code. Probably your algorithm is like this. on_click *If X children are visible, hide them. If not - show*. But you need - **If visible, hide children, if not, hide all children and show only this one's children.** Without your code I can only give you algorithm like this.

Comment: Ok, i add the code

Comment: You neglected to specify the _parent_, so Bootstrap does not know these items are supposed to belong together.

Answer (score 0):

I created a **[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zta8amc2/)** showing the algorithm I commented about:

```
if (child is visible){
   hide the child
} else {
   hide all the others
   show your child
}
```

But if you are sticking to Bootstrap, you should see [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425165/bootstrap-3-accordion-button-toggle-data-parent-not-working) top answer.

Comment: Can you try make this dont using divs, but ul and li ?

Comment: it doesn't matter. you can still use class names for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a problem, bootstrap's collapse doesn't hide by clicking anywhere else but only on an element with a data-toggle="collapse" attribute.

You can use something like this :

```
$("body:not(*LIST_OF_SERVICES_AND_PRICES*)").click(function() {
    $("*LIST_OF_SERVICES_AND_PRICES*").slideUp(250);
});
```