# Need to disappear the others buttons collapse list, once a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 3 buttons in btn-group, and I need to see the list of the button pressed only, Once the other button pressed the collapse list should disappear and should show only the button pressed list.

Kindly suggest.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group  btn-group-justified">
    <a href="#demo" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse">List 1</a>
    <a href="#demo1" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse">List 2</a>
    <a href="#demo2" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse">List 3</a>
  </div>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse in">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-link="row" class="rowlink">
        <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
          <td><a href="#inputmask">Input mask</a>
          </td>
          <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
            <td><a href="http://www.jasny.net/" target="_blank">jasny.net</a>
            </td>
            <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
              <td><a href="#rowlinkModal" data-toggle="modal">Launch modal</a>
              </td>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>


  <div id="demo1" class="collapse">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-link="row" class="rowlink">
        <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
          <td><a href="#inputmask">Input mask</a>
          </td>
          <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
            <td><a href="http://www.jasny.net/" target="_blank">jasny.net</a>
            </td>
            <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
              <td><a href="#rowlinkModal" data-toggle="modal">Launch modal</a>
              </td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-link="row" class="rowlink">
        <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
          <td><a href="#inputmask">Input mask</a>
          </td>
          <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
            <td><a href="http://www.jasny.net/" target="_blank">jasny.net</a>
            </td>
            <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
              <td><a href="#rowlinkModal" data-toggle="modal">Launch modal</a>
              </td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close, just need to add a few things....

1. Add an id to the div with class "container". This is needed for step 2
2. Add the data-parent attribute to the buttons and reference the id from step 1. The data-parent attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.
3. Wrap the collapsible elements in a div with class "panel". This is needed since bootstrap requires a certain order of elements. See the following answer for more details. [Bootstrap 3 Accordion button toggle "data-parent" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425165/bootstrap-3-accordion-button-toggle-data-parent-not-working)

Updated code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="container" class="container">
  <div class="btn-group  btn-group-justified">
    <a href="#demo" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#container">List 1</a>
    <a href="#demo1" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#container">List 2</a>
    <a href="#demo2" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#container">List 3</a>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
  <div id="demo" class="collapse in">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-link="row" class="rowlink">
        <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
          <td><a href="#inputmask">Input mask</a>
          </td>
          <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
            <td><a href="http://www.jasny.net/" target="_blank">jasny.net</a>
            </td>
            <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
              <td><a href="#rowlinkModal" data-toggle="modal">Launch modal</a>
              </td>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>


  <div id="demo1" class="collapse">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-link="row" class="rowlink">
        <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
          <td><a href="#inputmask">Input mask</a>
          </td>
          <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
            <td><a href="http://www.jasny.net/" target="_blank">jasny.net</a>
            </td>
            <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
              <td><a href="#rowlinkModal" data-toggle="modal">Launch modal</a>
              </td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-link="row" class="rowlink">
        <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
          <td><a href="#inputmask">Input mask</a>
          </td>
          <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
            <td><a href="http://www.jasny.net/" target="_blank">jasny.net</a>
            </td>
            <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
              <td><a href="#rowlinkModal" data-toggle="modal">Launch modal</a>
              </td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks the collapse is working fine. but the clickable-row is not working, before whole row was working as a link. Tested with onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com';" not working. pls suggest.

Comment: @Afzal - Can you please provide some more details? I am able to add the onclick to any TR element in my updated example and redirect appropriately.