# Convert Bootstrap 3.x list-group to Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The menu below is working on Bootstrap 4. However when I click on a list-group-item the already collapsed item will not close.

```
<div id="menu">
<div class="panel list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sm" data-parent="#menu">MESSAGES <span class="label label-info">5</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope pull-right"></span></a>
    <div id="sm" class="sublinks collapse">
        <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> inbox</a>
        <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> sent</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sl" data-parent="#menu">TASKS <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag pull-right"></span></a>
    <div id="sl" class="sublinks collapse">
        <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> saved tasks</a>
        <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> add new task</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">ANOTHER LINK ...<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats pull-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 3.x is [dependent on the `panel` class for accordion behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425165/bootstrap-3-accordion-button-toggle-data-parent-not-working/19426220#19426220).

In Bootstrap 4.x, `panel` has changed to `card`. Replace the `panel` in your code with `card`, and the accordion will work as expected...

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="card list-group"> <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sm" data-parent="#menu">MESSAGES <span class="badge badge-info">5</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope float-right"></span></a>
        <div id="sm" class="sublinks collapse"> <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> inbox</a>
            <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> sent</a>
        </div> <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sl" data-parent="#menu">TASKS <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag float-right"></span></a>
        <div id="sl" class="sublinks collapse"> <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> saved tasks</a>
            <a class="list-group-item small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> add new task</a>
        </div> <a href="#" class="list-group-item">ANOTHER LINK ...<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats float-right"></span></a>
    </div>
```

[Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/V7FSqjmaRD/bootstrap-4-accordion)