# collapse tabs "manually" don't change text on the initiate button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

Only when the button `#collapse_init` is clicked i manage to change the text on the button to "show all" or "hide all" according to the `active` Boolean variable

When I hide/collapse the tabs manually (one by one), the text on the button is not changed, i am trying to figure-up how to fix that.

- i mean, when all tabs are shown or not (but not through the button) - the button text is not changed.

** currently the pen is not working correctly- the button is not working correctly(only in the "pen", in my code it's working), it's not collapse/hide all in once (trying to figure why, also).

```js
var active = false;
$('#collapse_init').click(function () {               
  if (active) {
    active = false;
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
    $('.panel-title').attr('data-toggle', 'collapse');
    $(this).text('Show all');
  } else {
    active = true;
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('show');
    $('.panel-title').attr('data-toggle', '');
    $(this).text('Hide all');                    
  }
});

$('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {
  var visible = $('.accordion-toggle:visible').length; 
  if(visible >0){
     $('#collapse_init').text('Hide all');
  }else{
     $('#collapse_init').text('Show all');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <button id="collapse_init" class="btn btn-default ">Show all</button>
 <hr>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
            Collapsible Group Item #1
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
        <div class="panel-body">
          ONe Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
            Collapsible Group Item #2
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Two Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
            Collapsible Group Item #3
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Three Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CodePen**

[codepen](https://codepen.io/eranmeir1z/pen/Xgqryv)

Answer (score 2):

Add this code and try

```
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {
  var visible = $('.accordion-toggle:visible').length; 
  if(visible >0){
     $('#collapse_init').text('Hide all');
  }else{
     $('#collapse_init').text('Show all');
  }
});
```

Comment: I updated the pen with the code you suggested, its not working. try to show each tab (manually, one by one) the text on the button is not changed to "show all"

Comment: accordian is not working correctly in codepen. may be you can try in your code

Comment: or try with var visible = $('.collapse.in:visible').length;

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you're experiencing is that `$('.accordion-toggle:visible').length` is being retrieved **before** the panel has opened/closed.

You should use **shown.bs.collapse** and **hidden.bs.collapse** to detect when a panel has finished opening or closing.

Here's my crack. It's not quite there, but it's a fair bit cleaner (maybe).

```
var active = false,
$collapseBtn = $('#collapse_init'),
$accordion = $('#accordion');

$collapseBtn.on('click',function(){
  active = ! active;
  $('.panel-collapse').collapse( active ? 'show' : 'hide');
  $('.panel-title').attr('data-toggle', active ? '' : 'collapse' );
})

$accordion.on({
  'shown.bs.collapse': function () {
    active = true;
    $collapseBtn.text( 'Hide all' );
  },
  'hidden.bs.collapse': function ( e) {
    active = ! ! $('.panel-collapse:visible').length;
    $collapseBtn.text( ( active ? 'Hide' : 'Show' ) + ' all' );
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/jamespoel/pen/dRePNQ

Comment: what are tese classes mean? `hidden.bs.collapse` and `shown.bs.collapse` they are buit in what `boostrap collapse`?

Comment: also, what is `! !`  in `hidden.bs.collapse` function

Comment: They're not classes, they're events. They're called internally by bootstrap.

**shown.bs.collapse** Occurs when the collapsible element is fully shown
**hidden.bs.collapse** Occurs when the collapsible element is fully hidden

The double-bang (`! !`) in front of the `$('.panel-collapse:visible').length` is just a trick to quickly cast an integer to a boolean. It's basically the same as `$('.panel-collapse:visible').length > 0`; I just prefer it :)

More on that [here](http://brianflove.com/2014/09/02/whats-the-double-exclamation-mark-for-in-javascript/)

Comment: the code is working (i have changed the code a bit), i encountered a bug > "manually" hide 2 tabs > click the button "show all" > only one of them is showing (the second one still in hidden state).
there is a bug in that area , when you show/hide only one tab or more and then try to show/hide them all. How can i solve it?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why, but removing the `data-parent="#accordion"` from each panel solved this issue. I updated my codepen. :-)

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked! i find a way to solve the `data-parent="#accordion"` , i used the suggested work-around here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425165/bootstrap-3-accordion-button-toggle-data-parent-not-working