# Bootstrap Accordion without Bootstrap Panel Markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any feasible way to create a bootstrap accordion control without having to use the 'panels' markup??  I have the collapse control working but I would like to be able to target parents for each section in the control.

In other words, I would like the "Revenue" and "Margin" buckets to toggle each other and inside of "Revenue" have "Revenue Current", "Revenue Base", and "Revenue Current vs. Base" toggle each other without disturbing the parent layers.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lp903gc5/

**Markup**

```
<div class="group-by">
    <div class="jstree-preview group-dropdown">
        <ul id="j3_1">
            <li>
                <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-j3_2" data-parent="#j3_1" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">
                    <span>Revenue</span>
                    <i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i>
                </span>
                <ul class="collapse" id="collapse-j3_2" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                    <li>
                        <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-j3_3">
                            <span>Revenue Current </span>
                            <i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i>
                        </span>
                        <ul class="collapse" id="collapse-j3_3">
                            <li>
                                <span>Extended Zone Price</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Net Amount</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Revenue</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Revenue Share at DN</span>
                            </li>                            
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-j3_8">
                            <span>Revenue Base</span>
                            <i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i>
                        </span>
                        <ul class="collapse" id="collapse-j3_8">
                            <li>
                                <span>Extended Zone Price</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Net Amount</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Revenue</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Revenue Share at DN</span>
                            </li>                            
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-j3_13">
                            <span>Revenue Current Vs Base</span>
                            <i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i>
                        </span>
                        <ul class="collapse" id="collapse-j3_13">
                            <li>
                                <span>Matched Base Revenue</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Matched Current Revenue</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Matching %</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>New Sales Revenue</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Non-Repeat Revenue</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Normalized Base Revenue</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Revenue Change %</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Revenue Volume Change $</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Total Revenue Change $</span>
                            </li>                            
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-j3_23" data-parent="#j3_1" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">
                    <span>Margin</span>
                    <i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i>
                </span>
                <ul class="collapse" id="collapse-j3_23" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                    <li>
                        <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-j3_24">
                            <span>Margin Current</span>
                            <i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i>
                        </span>
                        <ul class="collapse" id="collapse-j3_24">
                            <li>
                                <span>In-scope Margin Index</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Margin</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Margin %</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Margin per Unit</span>
                            </li>                            
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-j3_29">
                            <span>Margin Base</span>
                            <i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i>
                        </span>
                        <ul class="collapse" id="collapse-j3_29">
                            <li>
                                <span>In-scope Margin Index</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Margin</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Margin %</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Margin per Unit</span>
                            </li>                            
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-j3_34">
                            <span>Margin Current Vs Base</span>
                            <i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i>
                        </span>
                        <ul class="collapse" id="collapse-j3_34">
                            <li>
                                <span>Margin % Change (bps)</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Margin Volume Change $</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Matched Base Margin</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Matched Current Margin</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>New Sales Margin</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Non-Repeat Margin</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Normalized Base Margin</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Total Margin % Change</span>
                            </li>                            
                            <li>
                                <span>Total Margin Change $</span>
                            </li>                            
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

The 3.x version of bootstrap requires a `panel` class added to the container of the toggler + togglee within the `data-parent`.

In your example, this can simply be done by adding `class="panel"` to the first and second depth of `<li>` elements. I've made an example using your code over here:
http://www.bootply.com/15nIagFMbk

In a simpler example:

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li class="panel">
        <a href="#c1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="collapsed">
            Toggle 1
        </a>
        <p id="c1" class="collapse">
            Some collapsable text 1
        </p>
    </li>
    <li class="panel">
        <a href="#c2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="collapsed">
            Toggle 2
        </a>
        <p id="c2" class="collapse">
            Some collapsable text 2
        </p>
    </li>
    <li class="panel">
        <a href="#c3" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="collapsed">
            Toggle 3
        </a>
        <p id="c3" class="collapse">
            Some collapsable text 3
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So simple. Why didn't I think of that? Great answer. Works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Just heard back from an actual Bootstrap developer saying that this is currently not possible but is a planned feature for Bootstrap v4.0.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but it would be fairly trivial to write your own jQuery to do this.

Comment: We can make this work **using Jquery** , check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11479208/2218697) post.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job

```
$("a[data-parent='#j3_1']").on("click", function() {
  var current = $(this).attr("href");
  current = $(current);
  $(".collapse.toplevel").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(current)) {
      $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

Rename  to

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but having the same issue and giving up know trying to implement it on a Wordpress site. This is the resulting code with Collapse working correctly but not maintaining only one open at the time as it should.

```html
<div id="faq-accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            
    <article id="post-12347" class="entry-post entry-post-fullwidth panel post-12347 faq type-faq status-publish format-standard hentry faq_category-reservas">
        <div class="entry-content">
            <header id="heading-12347" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faq-accordion" href="#collapse-12347" class="" aria-expanded="true">
                    <h1 class="entry-title">HEADLINE ACC1</h1>        
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->

            <div id="collapse-12347" class="entry-summary collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-12347" aria-expanded="true" style="">
                <p>answer to HEADLINE ACC</p>
                <div class="entry-footer"></div><!-- .entry-footer -->
            </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </article><!-- #post-## -->

            
    <article id="post-12365" class="entry-post entry-post-fullwidth panel post-12365 faq type-faq status-publish format-standard hentry faq_category-reservas">
        <div class="entry-content">
            <header id="heading-12365" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#faq-accordion" href="#collapse-12365" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">
                    <h1 class="entry-title">HEADLINE ACC2</h1>        
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->

            <div id="collapse-12365" class="entry-summary collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-12365" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
              answer 2
            </div>
                <div class="entry-footer"></div><!-- .entry-footer -->
            </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    </article><!-- #post-## -->

</div>
```