# Bootstrap Collapse - close other on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap/Collapse for these 3 buttons. You can see it live  [here](http://www.shakk.cz/mikiny) - those 3 yellow buttons. When I click on the first button and then on the second button, I want to close the first div by clicking the second. Can you help me how can I do it?

here's some supporting code:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="collapse" href="#price" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="price">Podle ceny</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="collapse" href="#manufacturers" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="manufacturers">Podle značky</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="collapse" href="#13" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="13">Podle velikosti</a>

<ul>
  <li data-type="price" data-base-type="price" data-id="price" data-seo-name="price" data-inline-horizontal="0" data-display-live-filter="0" data-display-list-of-items="" class="mfilter-filter-item mfilter-price mfilter-price collapse" id="price">
  ...
  </li>
  <li data-type="checkbox" data-base-type="manufacturers" data-id="manufacturers" data-seo-name="manufacturers" data-inline-horizontal="0" data-display-live-filter="0" data-display-list-of-items="" class="mfilter-filter-item mfilter-checkbox mfilter-manufacturers collapse" id="manufacturers">
  ...
  </li>
  <li data-type="checkbox" data-base-type="option" data-id="13" data-seo-name="13o-velikost" data-inline-horizontal="0" data-display-live-filter="0" data-display-list-of-items="" class="mfilter-filter-item mfilter-checkbox mfilter-option mfilter-options collapse" id="13">
  ...
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Please don't expect people fish for the relevant code in your production website.

Comment: I am using just the code which I wrote in the first question. Nothing more.

Comment: Your issue seems to be fixed in this SO Post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476670/bootstrap-collapse-other-sections-when-one-is-expanded

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to achieve the desired output would be by using jquery. I have implemented the similar feature by using script written here. You can run on your system and look for the effect.

```
`<script>` `src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js</script>`

`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button1").click(function(){
    $('#button1').html("<p>"+"hello"+"</p>");
  })
  $("#button2").click(function(){
    $('#button2').html("<li>"+"hello"+"</li>");
    $('p').hide();
  })
  $("#button3").click(function(){
    $('#button3').html("<li>"+"hello"+"</li>");
  $('#button2').find('li').hide();
  })
})
</script>`
```

Attach three button with id button1 ,button2 and button3 inside body tag of html code .

Now to get the exact functionality replace the class name and id to achieve the exact feature.