# Making last dynamic added accordion open

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add bootstrap [accordion](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#accordion-example) programmatically so that every time I click ADD button, a new accordion get generated and the previous or any other closes. I cannot figure out bootstrap docs on how to use [methods](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#methods) and what options to pass, I have placed few of mine but it doesn't work.

```
if(this.aCount === 1){
   $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
 }else if(this.aCount === 2){
   $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
   $('.collapse').collapse('show');
 }
```

The problem is my id on accordion are dynamic, so I cannot use that but in total my script generate 3 accordion and on every time it add a new accordion, I want to open recently added one and close any open ones. Right now It opens the very first one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/14hp0t7L/), try this one. I am using jquery `toggle()` method to open and close each div when clicked. Then I used `siblings()` to call the relative div element.

I'm not using bootstrap in here. :) 

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Not sure how can I apply your example to mine.

Comment: Ah okay @Nofel, Why?

Comment: I tried `  $('.collapse').siblings().collapse('hide');` but it didn't work.

Comment: do you have your html code ? pls provide it to your question so we can try how to apply this code :)

Comment: I am using [TBS collapse](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/)

Comment: On the left panel 'External Resources' I have called the bootstrap css and bootstrap js

Comment: If you want not show the first div, just remove the `show` class on the first collapse div

Answer (score 0):

You can "Delegate Events" in jQuery using the .on method in order to bind events to dynamically created elements:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.collapse', function (e)
{
    // SOME .collapse WAS CLICKED!
    jQuery('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

This way, every time a .collapse element is clicked - even if the element was created dynamically - all the others will close.

Comment: I got it working, but now my code is running again and again (I guess), So when it is hidden, it doesn't change the minus. Here is my new [codepen](https://codepen.io/codearts/pen/dzwdyj)

Comment: @Nofel here's a forked version of your pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqRXZz I simplified something here and there.

Comment: It is not working as it should. The red border is an indication of which div is open as plus/minus and ur plus minus doesn't work.

Comment: @Nofel I updated the fork. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqRXZz Now it works but it's super ugly. The position of the SPAN element in your markup is very odd, consider applying plus and minus classes on a:after