# How to collapse section when other second opens? (Bootstrap)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

How would you make the small business section close when one opens the big business section, and vice versa?

I am still unable to get it even with the help of this post:
[Bootstrap: Collapse other sections when one is expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476670/bootstrap-collapse-other-sections-when-one-is-expanded)

Below is my code:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-10">
       <div>
         <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data target="#small" data-parent="#smb" aria-expanded="false">
            Small Business</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-10" id="business">
      <div>
        <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#big" data-parent="#smb" aria-expanded="false">
          Big Business</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="smb">
    <div class="collapse" id="small">
      <h1>Generate New Growth</h1>      
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="big">   
      <h1>Propagate More Growth</h1>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's [Accordion behavior](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) only works on `.panel` so you will need to use one of the JavaScript methods mentioned on the link you referred to in your question.

eg. Add a wrapper div around the controls and sections:

```
<div id="smb">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-10">
      <div>
        <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#small" data-parent="#smb" aria-expanded="false">
            Small Business</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-10" id="business">
      <div>
        <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#big" data-parent="#smb" aria-expanded="false">
          Big Business</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="collapse" id="small">
      <h1>Generate New Growth</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="big">
      <h1>Propagate More Growth</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
var $myGroup = $('#smb');
$myGroup.on('show.bs.collapse', '.collapse', function() {
    $myGroup.find('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
});
```

Demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjny6ctn/3/).