# I need help collapsing one when expanding another using bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have four div cards that act as buttons so that I can collapse and expand information under the row of cards. I'm trying to have it to where when I click one card the information expands below and if I click a different card it collapses the first information and expands the second card's information. but when I tried to implement that for some reason its not collapsing card 1 and epanding card 2's information its just stacking.  I tried looking it up here and came across this question that was already answered. I implemented the answer but something's not working could anyone help me figure out why. here's the answered question I referenced

[Bootstrap: Collapse other sections when one is expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476670/bootstrap-collapse-other-sections-when-one-is-expanded)

This is the answer to that post. I put that in my code but it doesn't work.

[Screen Capture Of Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Czl.png)

I've also tried other answers but nothing seems to work

here is my code

```css
p, h1 {
 font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
}







.containerS {
 margin-right: 2%;
 margin-left: 2%;
}

.card:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 9px 40px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 9px 40px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: -1px 9px 40px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    transform: scale(1.02)

}
.card {
  
 border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #bb9c4c;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    align: center;
    transition: transform .1s;
    color: black;
}
.card img {
 transition: transform .1s
}

.card img:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.01);
}



.btn {
 background-color: #bb9c4c;
 border-color: #bb9c4c;
}
.card-body {
 padding: 10px;
}


.services {
 background-color:#242424;
  color:white;
 padding:90px 0 90px;
 text-align:center;
 overflow: hidden;
}



.services h1 {
 font-size:2em;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.services h3 { 
 font-weight:normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>


<div class="services" id="services">
      <div class="containerS">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <h1>Meow</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div id="myGroup">
           <div class="row">
             <div id="mentor" class="colo-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 wow flipInY" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
               <div class="card" style="width:100%;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample1" data-parent="#myGroup" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample1">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Card One" class="card-img-top" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title">Meow 1</h5>
                </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div id="sales" class="colo-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 wow flipInY" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
               <div class="card" style="width:100%;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample2" data-parent="#myGroup" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Card One" class="card-img-top" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title">Meow 2</h5>
                </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div id="strat" class="colo-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 wow flipInY" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
               <div class="card" style="width:100%" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample3" data-parent="#myGroup" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample3">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Card One" class="card-img-top" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title">Meow 3</h5>
                </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div id="security" class="colo-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 wow flipInY" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
               <div class="card" style="width:100%;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample4" data-parent="#myGroup" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample4">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Card One" class="card-img-top" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title">Meow 4</h5>
                </div>
               </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="collapse colo-lg-12 col-md-12 indent" id="collapseExample1" style="width:100%;">
     <div class="card card-body" style="width:100%">
          1Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.Mauris tempor vulputate dolor, nec convallis turpis luctus quis. Morbi id justo vel diam dignissim commodo. Aenean id luctus libero, vel gravida magna. Vestibulum ac purus lobortis, varius tellus non, rhoncus sapien. Mauris elementum, nisl sed interdum venenatis, metus enim pellentesque massa, eget laoreet eros ex vitae felis. Curabitur vitae rhoncus odio, sit amet porta tortor. Duis in mollis odio.
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse colo-lg-12 col-md-12 indent" id="collapseExample2" style="width:100%;">
     <div class="card card-body" style="width:100%">
          2Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.Mauris tempor vulputate dolor, nec convallis turpis luctus quis. Morbi id justo vel diam dignissim commodo. Aenean id luctus libero, vel gravida magna. Vestibulum ac purus lobortis, varius tellus non, rhoncus sapien. Mauris elementum, nisl sed interdum venenatis, metus enim pellentesque massa, eget laoreet eros ex vitae felis. Curabitur vitae rhoncus odio, sit amet porta tortor. Duis in mollis odio.
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse colo-lg-12 col-md-12 indent" id="collapseExample3" style="width:100%;">
     <div class="card card-body" style="width:100%">
          3Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.Mauris tempor vulputate dolor, nec convallis turpis luctus quis. Morbi id justo vel diam dignissim commodo. Aenean id luctus libero, vel gravida magna. Vestibulum ac purus lobortis, varius tellus non, rhoncus sapien. Mauris elementum, nisl sed interdum venenatis, metus enim pellentesque massa, eget laoreet eros ex vitae felis. Curabitur vitae rhoncus odio, sit amet porta tortor. Duis in mollis odio.
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse colo-lg-12 col-md-12 indent" id="collapseExample4" style="width:100%;">
     <div class="card card-body" style="width:100%">
          4Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.Mauris tempor vulputate dolor, nec convallis turpis luctus quis. Morbi id justo vel diam dignissim commodo. Aenean id luctus libero, vel gravida magna. Vestibulum ac purus lobortis, varius tellus non, rhoncus sapien. Mauris elementum, nisl sed interdum venenatis, metus enim pellentesque massa, eget laoreet eros ex vitae felis. Curabitur vitae rhoncus odio, sit amet porta tortor. Duis in mollis odio.
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you already tried ?

Comment: The top rated answer is what I have implemented in this post but I've tried all of the other answers but they didn't work ill add the answer to my post

Comment: would you like to use javascript?. I can't find the problem in the html for now

Comment: yes anything that can get the job done I'm open to anything Thank you!

Comment: No need for js now I found the problem check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `data-parent="#myGroup"` should be in the div that have the `collapse` class

```css
p, h1 {
 font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
}

.containerS {
 margin-right: 2%;
 margin-left: 2%;
}

.card:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 9px 40px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 9px 40px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: -1px 9px 40px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    transform: scale(1.02)

}
.card {
  
 border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #bb9c4c;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    align: center;
    transition: transform .1s;
    color: black;
}
.card img {
 transition: transform .1s
}

.card img:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.01);
}



.btn {
 background-color: #bb9c4c;
 border-color: #bb9c4c;
}
.card-body {
 padding: 10px;
}


.services {
 background-color:#242424;
  color:white;
 padding:90px 0 90px;
 text-align:center;
 overflow: hidden;
}



.services h1 {
 font-size:2em;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.services h3 { 
 font-weight:normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>


<div class="services" id="services">
      <div class="containerS">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <h1>Meow</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div id="myGroup">
           <div class="row">
             <div id="mentor" class="colo-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 wow flipInY" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
               <div class="card" style="width:100%;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample1">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Card One" class="card-img-top" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title">Meow 1</h5>
                </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div id="sales" class="colo-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 wow flipInY" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
               <div class="card" style="width:100%;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Card One" class="card-img-top" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title">Meow 2</h5>
                </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div id="strat" class="colo-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 wow flipInY" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
               <div class="card" style="width:100%" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample3" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample3">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Card One" class="card-img-top" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title">Meow 3</h5>
                </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div id="security" class="colo-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 wow flipInY" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
               <div class="card" style="width:100%;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample4" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample4">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="Card One" class="card-img-top" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="card-body">
                 <h5 class="card-title">Meow 4</h5>
                </div>
               </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="collapse colo-lg-12 col-md-12 indent" id="collapseExample1" data-parent="#myGroup" style="width:100%;">
     <div class="card card-body" style="width:100%">
          1Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.Mauris tempor vulputate dolor, nec convallis turpis luctus quis. Morbi id justo vel diam dignissim commodo. Aenean id luctus libero, vel gravida magna. Vestibulum ac purus lobortis, varius tellus non, rhoncus sapien. Mauris elementum, nisl sed interdum venenatis, metus enim pellentesque massa, eget laoreet eros ex vitae felis. Curabitur vitae rhoncus odio, sit amet porta tortor. Duis in mollis odio.
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse colo-lg-12 col-md-12 indent" id="collapseExample2" data-parent="#myGroup" style="width:100%;">
     <div class="card card-body" style="width:100%">
          2Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.Mauris tempor vulputate dolor, nec convallis turpis luctus quis. Morbi id justo vel diam dignissim commodo. Aenean id luctus libero, vel gravida magna. Vestibulum ac purus lobortis, varius tellus non, rhoncus sapien. Mauris elementum, nisl sed interdum venenatis, metus enim pellentesque massa, eget laoreet eros ex vitae felis. Curabitur vitae rhoncus odio, sit amet porta tortor. Duis in mollis odio.
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse colo-lg-12 col-md-12 indent" id="collapseExample3" data-parent="#myGroup" style="width:100%;">
     <div class="card card-body" style="width:100%">
          3Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.Mauris tempor vulputate dolor, nec convallis turpis luctus quis. Morbi id justo vel diam dignissim commodo. Aenean id luctus libero, vel gravida magna. Vestibulum ac purus lobortis, varius tellus non, rhoncus sapien. Mauris elementum, nisl sed interdum venenatis, metus enim pellentesque massa, eget laoreet eros ex vitae felis. Curabitur vitae rhoncus odio, sit amet porta tortor. Duis in mollis odio.
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse colo-lg-12 col-md-12 indent" id="collapseExample4" data-parent="#myGroup" style="width:100%;">
     <div class="card card-body" style="width:100%">
          4Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.Mauris tempor vulputate dolor, nec convallis turpis luctus quis. Morbi id justo vel diam dignissim commodo. Aenean id luctus libero, vel gravida magna. Vestibulum ac purus lobortis, varius tellus non, rhoncus sapien. Mauris elementum, nisl sed interdum venenatis, metus enim pellentesque massa, eget laoreet eros ex vitae felis. Curabitur vitae rhoncus odio, sit amet porta tortor. Duis in mollis odio.
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you I implemented that and it worked! I also had old javascript that was messing with it as well in my main file.

Comment: @AliceRay Great then