# Looping to organize and display custom posts by category using PHP and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I am developing a page that requires me to display a list of categories for a custom post type in an accordion-style dropdown. The category name will act as the accordion title, and the contents are to be the posts associated with each particular category. The image below summarizes what I would ultimately accomplish.

[image: Bootstrap Accordion drop-down for categories mock-up]

I've be able to successfully retrieve the category names and assign them to an accordion dropdown, but what is happening is that my code is adding new cells even though the two posts are associated with the similar category name.

[image: Bootstrap Accordion drop-down duplicating categories]

Arrrrrg, I feel like i'm so close! Here's a snippet of what my code looks like so far.

```
<div id="accordion" class="col-8" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
              <?php 
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'our_work',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'orderby' => 'category',
                        'hide_empty' => 0,
                    );  
                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                ?>
        <div class="card box-shadow">

            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php the_ID(); ?>"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <?php
                          foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
                              echo $category->cat_name . ' '; 
                          }
                        ?>
                    </a>
                </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapse<?php the_ID(); ?>" style="transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;" class="collapse nomnom"
                role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <p><?php the_Content(); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
```

What I suspect is going on is that I don't have my loop set up properly and is adding a new cell as a result.

I am still fairly new to working with the 'WordPress loop', so any advice would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to use echo instead. This should be cleaner and hopefully work (untested)

```
  <?php 
   $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'our_work',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'orderby' => 'category',
      'hide_empty' => 0,
   );  
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  $cat = '';//set a variable to catch category
  $first = 0;
  echo '<div id="accordion" class="col-8" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">';
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $post_cat = '';
    foreach(( get_the_category() ) as $category) { 
      $post_cat = $category->cat_name . ' '; 
    }
    if($first == 0){
      $first = 1;
      $cat = $post_cat;
      echo '<div class="card box-shadow">';
      echo'<div class="card-header" role="tab" id="'.get_the_id().'">';
      echo'<h5 class="mb-0">';
      echo'<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse'.get_the_id().'"aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">'.$post_cat.'</a>';
      echo'</h5>';
      echo'</div>';
      //start collapse pannel
      echo'<div id="collapse'.get_the_id().'" style="transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;" class="collapse nomnom" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading'.get_the_id().'">';
    }
    if($cat != $post_cat){
      $cat = $post_cat;
      echo'</div>';//close collapse
      echo'</div>';//close box shadow
      echo '<div class="card box-shadow">';
      echo'<div class="card-header" role="tab" id="'.get_the_id().'">';
      echo'<h5 class="mb-0">';
      echo'<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse'.get_the_id().'"aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">'.$post_cat.'</a>';
      echo'</h5>';
      echo'</div>';
      //start collapse pannel
      echo'<div id="collapse'.get_the_id().'" style="transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;" class="collapse nomnom" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading'.get_the_id().'">';
    }
    echo'<div class="card-block">';
    echo'<h1>'.get_the_title().'</h1>';
    echo'<p>'.get_the_content().'</p>';
    echo'</div>';  
    if (($loop->current_post +1) == ($loop->post_count)) { 
      echo '</div>';//close collapse 
      echo '</div>';//box shadow close
    } 
  endwhile; 
  wp_reset_query();
  echo '</div>';//close accordian close
    ?>
```

Comment: I took the above code and tested it, but alas it is not working properly.

 [link](https://imgur.com/a/sdOjcP2)

It looks like the loop is getting hung up on the first post and then breaks

Comment: After replacing the old code with the edited version, the loop is not functioning properly [see first](https://imgur.com/a/S7OnJzA).

It appears that all the categories AND custom posts are being assigned to the first accordion item, then opens and displays all content.
[see second](https://imgur.com/a/8oTZaPO).

I really appreciate your time and patience in helping me deal with this issue!

Comment: @abihuniak hmm. I am guessing then that the $post_cat value is not getting set I have modified my code.  Please check if that helps. If not could you share with me the rendered html

Comment: Here's a img of what the inspector is telling me [picture here](https://i.imgur.com/Ep5eMoh.png).

You're onto something. While evaluating the inspector, it appears that the **IDs** are not getting appended when the page is rendered

Comment: Ok. looking at it. i just adjusted my code so that it wont print the id's please try the new code

Comment: @abihuniak  Found another mistake, accidentally did $first == 1 instead of $first = 1; Code is updated now. give it a shot.

Comment: hey @Hans-Eric is there a way to close a tab once another tab is clicked? Right now they all stay open when a new tab is clicked

Comment: Ya that can be done. Best way to do it would be with javascript.  Something like this should point you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476670/bootstrap-collapse-other-sections-when-one-is-expanded