# Div. Toggle with button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a form and want different divs to show when different button is click but can't make it work I used data-toggle with bootstrap but it is showing both the div together

This first image is what happens when I click billed monthly

[image]

In the second image when I click billed yearly the first div is also showing but I want that only second div is visible

when you click on billed monthly first and then on billed yearly next both the divs are visible and i only want that one shoul be visible like if you first click billed monthly the div related to it should show and if you click billed yearly next the billed monthly div should hide and only bileed yearly div should be visible.

[image]

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row justify-content-evenly">

  <div class="col d-grid gap-2 col-3 mt-4 mb-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="billed-monthly" value="monthly" style="border: solid 1px grey;" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#billmonthly" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Billed Monthly</button>

  </div>
  <div class="col d-grid gap-2 col-3 mt-4 mb-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="billed-yearly" value="yearly" style="border: solid 1px grey;" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#billyearly" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Billed Yearly</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row mt-2 collapse" id="billmonthly">
  <div class=" col d-flex justify-content-end">
    <h3>Billed now: 199</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-2 collapse" id="billmonthly">
  <div class=" col d-flex justify-content-end">
    <p>By clicking "Start Premium Plan", you agree to be charge 199 every<br> month, unless you cancel. You acknowledge that refunds won't be<br> available on cancellation.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-2 collapse" id="billyearly">
  <div class=" col d-flex justify-content-end">
    <h3>Billed now: 2030</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-2 collapse" id="billyearly">
  <div class=" col d-flex justify-content-end">
    <p>By clicking "Start Premium Plan", you agree to be charge 2030 every<br> year, unless you cancel. You acknowledge that refunds won't be<br> available on cancellation.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: BS5: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66288374/295783

Answer (score -1):

I have created a demo for you to acquire your functionality. Please note that I am not using Bootstrap. It's complete jQuery methods.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="billNow">Bill Now </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="#" id="billYearly">Bill Yearly </a><br/><br/>
<div id="showdetails">
    <div id="billnowdetails">
        <p>details of Bill now</p>
    </div>
    <div id="billyeardetails">
    <p>details of Bill Yearly</p></div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
let billnow = $("#billnowdetails").remove();
let billyear = $("#billyeardetails").remove();
    $("#billNow").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#showdetails").find("#billyeardetails").remove();
        $("#showdetails").append(billnow);
    });
    
    $("#billYearly").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#showdetails").find("#billnowdetails").remove();
        $("#showdetails").append(billyear);
    });
});
</script>
```

NOTE: If you want to check the outcome. you can copy and paste code https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_lib_google here.

Comment: That is horrible. Why remove from DOM when you can toggle display?
Also w3schools is a poor resource

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43050573/295783

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66288374/295783

Comment: yes i am removing it as only one of them is needed. Further as you stated collapse. collapse just collapses your div and not hides. here the functionality is to show only the corresponding division.

Comment: @mplungjan in this manner `hide` is more suitable option than using collapse. I have already highlighted in my answer that **I am using pure jquery and not bootstrap.** also stated that this is a hard way.

Comment: as of w3school, I have provided him where he can test the code. thats everyone choice if you want to use sandbook or codepen thats upto him.

Comment: OP is already using bootstrap  - at least hide instead of remove. Depending on the size of the page, removing and inserting into DOM is not recommended

Comment: Also SO has a stacksnippet editor so ppl do not have to leave SO to see running code. Click `[<>]` button in the editor