# Only show one collapse open (Vue 3 / Bootstrap 5)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I'm working with `Bootstrap5` and `Vue 3`. I have multiple `buttons` and each of them is triggering one `collapse`.

What I want is that if I open one collapse all other collapse should be closed. But now every collapse will be shown and the other ones are not closing.

I've tried to use `data-parent` and `data-bs-parent` but non of this is working.

How can I achive that? Thank You!

```
<div class="row margin-top">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn color-success" style="height: 200px;" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse-b1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-b1" data-bs-parent="#myGroup">
        Button 1
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn color-primary" style="height: 200px;" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse-b2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-b2" data-bs-parent="#myGroup">
        Button 2
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapse-b1">
    <div class="mt-3">
      Text 1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse" id="collapse-b2">
    <div class="mt-3">
      Text 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**A few minor changes to make it work**

Your code requires some minor fixes to work correctly. Add the `data-bs-parent="#myGroup"` attribute to each collapse. And then assign the same id to the parent element of *the collapsible elements*, i.e., the container.

Note that attribute name has been changed from `data-parent` in Bootstrap 4 to `data-bs-parent` in Bootstrap 5. And the parent is the element that contains the collapsible elements and **NOT** the container of the buttons and links used to toggle.

Additionally, buttons need to have the correct classes applied, e.g., `btn-primary` and `btn-success`.

Related SO Question: [Collapse other sections when one is expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476670/bootstrap-collapse-other-sections-when-one-is-expanded)

**Run the snippet to see how it works:**

```html
<div class="row margin-top">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="height: auto;" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse-b1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-b1">
        Button 1
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="height: auto;" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse-b2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-b2">
        Button 2
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="myGroup">  <!-- Add the parent id here -->

  <div class="collapse" id="collapse-b1"  data-bs-parent="#myGroup">
    <div class="alert alert-success mt-3">
      Text 1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse" id="collapse-b2" data-bs-parent="#myGroup">
    <div class="alert alert-primary mt-3">
      Text 2
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```